# Owl Carousel width issue on devices

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

I have an issue with an Owl Carousel (v2.3.4) that I can't see how to fix. On devices it seems to randomly resize the carousel and the images disappear. Sometimes I can see the Carousel has loaded correctly but then suddenly changes, it also seems to change when I interact with another Owl Carousel I have loaded. I have tried adding a separate wrapper to control the width, using one / two calls to load the two Carousels, delaying initialization etc..

It is the second Owl Carousel in the Green block that has the above issues. You can see the development page here: http://37.128.128.31/~thecropbrighton/

As I only want this slider to be on devices I am currently using the below Javascript:

```
$(function() {

if ($(window).width() < 768) {

    startCarousel();

  } else {

    $('.mob-carousel').addClass('off');

  }

  $(window).on('resize', function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {

      startCarousel();

    } else {

      stopCarousel();

  }

});

function startCarousel() {
  $('.mob-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    items: 1,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    navText: ["<img src='" + get_template_directory_uri + "/assets/images/right.svg'>", "<img src='" + get_template_directory_uri + "/assets/images/swipe-left.svg'>"],
  });
}

function stopCarousel() {
    var owl = $('.mob-carousel');
    owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
    owl.addClass('off');
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting responsive breakpoints? and their properties in that. if not have a look please https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: Thanks Awais, I have tried this but makes no difference. Interestingly autoWidth:true fixes the issue but this obviously makes you able to see more than 1 item. Maybe there's a work around using this?

Comment: If you set `item` number in break points to `1` then it should show only one item that's how carousel works. and can you please update the code with the latest one or may be its good make a minimal example of your code so far Thanks

Comment: Each slider you call needs a unique selector class (or ID); they will get confused if you bind to both (in fact I think they will act together/have weird behaviour otherwise). Owl slider also comes with built in responsive breakpoint options in the JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

on owl-carousel write "autoWidth: true", it will set auto width.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).